# Kompose doesn't bring up localhost for openzipkin and Elastic

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, kompose

I am new to K8s and I am trying to migrate my service (which currently utilizes docker-compose.yml) to k8s. My service

> deploys zipkin and elasticsearch

and these can be accessed at `'localhost:9411'` and `'localhost:9200'` respectively.

The most commonly used solution I found online was 'kompose' and I tried to run,

1. `kompose up`

2.

```
kompose convert

kubectl apply -f *****-deployment.yaml, ****-service.yaml
```

Once I finish this, I run kubectl get pods and I can see my deployments, but elasticsearch and zipkin are no more responsive on their respective localhost ports.

Ouput of `'kubectl get pods'`

[image: <code>kubectl get pods</code> (ignore migration)]

Output of `'docker ps'`

[image: <code>docker ps</code> (ignore migration)]

Output of `curl http://localhost:9200`

[image]

Can someone tell me why this is happening and how to debug?

Answer (score 0):

It is solved now; all I had to do was port forwarding.

```
kubectl port-forward zipkin-774cc77659-g929n 9411:9411
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

By default you service is exposed as **ClusterIP**, in this case your service will be accessible from within your cluster.

You can use port forwarding "**With this connection in place you can use your local workstation to debug your application that is running in the pod**" as described in the answer above.

Another approach is to use other *"service types"* like **NodePort**.

You can find more information here [Publishing services (ServiceTypes)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types)